# how to implement File Locking in java 6 for both windows and linux

Tags: java, java-io

In my project, i need to imeplement file locking and the problem is that we need to use **java 6** only so what are the ways through which i can implement file locking for both platform(windows/linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nio API for that. Find the below code snippet. It will help you to solve your problem

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    java.nio.channels.FileLock lck = in.getChannel().lock();
    try {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, charset);
        ...
    } finally {
        lck.release();
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

For more details you can refer java docs for FileLock
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html#pdep